# Extracting text between link tags using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have HTML code that looks like this:

```
<a href="/Content.aspx?id=102966" id="mylink" target="_blank">EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN - <img src="/images/usa.png" style="border:none; height:14px; margin-bottom:-2px;"/> Nationwide - <span title="college students/staff of schools in valid states">Restrictions</span> - Ends 6/30/15</a>
```

and I'm trying to extract the text displayed when this HTML is rendered.

More specifically, for this example 'a' tag, I'm trying to extract "EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN - Nationwide - Restrictions - Ends 6/30/15"

but I'm having trouble extracting the full text since it's broken up by an 'img' tag and 'span'.

To provide more context, I've been using the code below to search through all the 'a' tags and extract the link text.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', id='mylink'):
    raw.append(link)
    link_text = link.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
    sweeps.append(link_text)

#output: 'EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN - '
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do like this MWE, using `link.text` instead of `link.contents`

```
text = """
<a href="/Content.aspx?id=102966" id="mylink" target="_blank">EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN - <img src="/images/usa.png" style="border:none; height:14px; margin-bottom:-2px;"/> Nationwide - <span title="college students/staff of schools in valid states">Restrictions</span> - Ends 6/30/15</a>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

for link in soup.find_all('a', id='mylink'):
    link_text = link.text
    print link_text
```

result:

```
EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN -  Nationwide - Restrictions - Ends 6/30/15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could using regular to find all text

```
import urllib,urllib2,re

content=r'<a href="/Content.aspx?id=102966" id="mylink" target="_blank">EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN - <img src="/images/usa.png" style="border:none; height:14px; margin-bottom:-2px;"/> Nationwide - <span title="college students/staff of schools in valid states">Restrictions</span> - Ends 6/30/15</a>''



links=re.findall(r'>(.*?)<',content)
a=""
for link in links:
    a=a+link
print a
```

return "EZSTORAGE - PACK IT. STORE IT. WIN -  Nationwide - Restrictions - Ends 6/30/15"